# Protobuf could not be applied during project evaluation

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to compile protobuf, with this code in app

> build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.5'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.google.sample.helloandroidjni"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 17
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            plugins {
                apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
            }
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-android-jni"
    }
    android.packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'plugin.xml'
    }

}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile files('build/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

But I got the error:

> Error:The com.google.protobuf plugin could not be applied during
>   project evaluation. The Java plugin or one of the Android plugins must
>   be applied to the project first.

When I add `apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'`

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems the protobuf plugin just does not support the incubating `com.android.model.library` plugin.

Comment: how should I do to be able to add protobuf to android?